# Using jQuery to show table with links when mouseover picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make table with several links to show up with jQuery when mouse goes over and image. This works but the table hides when I move my mouse off the image. I need to table to be visible when I get the mouse over the table. I am new to programming and I wish you could help me.

Here is the HTML-table:

```
<table class="menu">
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top" width="130">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a><br />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" width="130">
                            <a href="#">Link 4</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Link 5</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Link 6</a><br />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" width="130">
                            <a href="#">Link 7</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Link 8</a><br />
                            <a href="#">Link 9</a><br />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.picture').mouseover(function(){
        $('.menu').fadeIn('fast');
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.picture').mouseleave(function(){
          $('.menu').fadeOut('fast');
      });
    });
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what is outcome of this code? and can you post your pic tag too please?

Comment: simplest approach is to have table and image in same parent and use mouse events on parent

Comment: click on the link which i have given there in my answer. there is a working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution as suggested by @Charlietfl:

**HTML**

```
<div class="picture-div">
    <img src="..." class="picture"/>
    <table class="menu">
    .......
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.picture-div').mouseover(function(){
        $('.menu').fadeIn('fast');
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $('.menu').fadeOut('fast');
    })
    .mouseleave();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.picture-div').mouseover(function() {
      $('.menu').fadeIn('fast');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.menu').fadeOut('fast');
    })
    .mouseleave();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picture-div">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJpEmL0wgaSxG8Ne8PaY6C9uz39g4KNy9H8Gaiu-kLgLZbyqZp" class="picture" />
  <table class="menu">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="130">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <br />
      </td>
      <td valign="top" width="130">
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        <br />
      </td>
      <td valign="top" width="130">
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        <br />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem I had! Now the next thing I am having a problem with is that I have 4 of these pictures displayed inline and when mouseover is executed on first one (one on the left) the table fades in and all the rest of the pictures are placed under the table.

Comment: And that was solved with absolute positioning inside relative positioned parent div. Thank you very much for the help, PeterKA and @charlietfl !!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your code should work if you remove a couple things.  You don't need two $(document).ready calls, you should just wrap everything in one.  So, if you change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.picture').mouseover(function(){
    $('.menu').fadeIn('fast');
  })
})
```

Everything should work fine.  Also make sure the in your CSS, the table has a display on none or hidden.

Comment: this won't change behavior of OP code. Should be fairly obvious that user can't access the links within `.menu`

Comment: You're right, I completely missed that part.  I'll edit my answer.